# Circular shifting an array with `memmove`

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memmove

Say I have an integer array like such

```
#define MAX 5
int bar [MAX] = {0};
int foo [MAX] = {3,1,0,0,0};
```

Now I'd like to shift this array so that all null entries are to the left, i.e. `bar = {0,0,0,3,1}`.

I thought I could do this by

1. Finding the number of shifts I must perform
2. Using `memmove()` to do the shift.

I solved 1. with the following loop

```
for (shift = MAX - 1; shift >= 0; --shift) {
    if (foo[shift]) break;
}
```

But I do not know how to use `memmove()` now to perform the shift, I attempted to do `memmove(bar + shift, foo, MAX * sizeof(*foo)-1);` but with no success.

Is `memmove()` the correct tool for the job? How can I circulate an integer array as described? What if this is happening inside a function where `bar` is a passed as a pointer?

Comment: How will you shift in the shifted out elements?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I guess I would need another `memmove`?

Comment: And an intermediate buffet to store them, apparently.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Do I need an intermediate buffer? I'm moving `foo` into `bar`, so `foo` will be intact, no? Couldn't I just move `foo` again?

Comment: Right. Though you want it in-place. In this case you can use `memcpy` instead..

Comment: @chqrlie Am I? It is possible that I've misread something..

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I thought the *shift* was meant to happen in place, `memcpy` is fine to move the appropriate elements into the right places into `bar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The formula you used to calculate `shift` does not give you the number of positions by which to shift.
- You're not moving the correct number of bytes (`MAX * sizeof(*foo)-1` is in no way based on the number of trailing zeroes).

---

```
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 5
int bar[MAX] = {0};
int foo[MAX] = {3,1,0,0,0};

int i;
int shift = 0;
for (i=MAX; i--; ) {
   if (foo[i]) {
      shift = MAX - (i + 1);
      break;
   }
}

memcpy(bar+shift, foo, (MAX-shift) * sizeof(*foo));
memcpy(bar, foo+(MAX-shift), shift * sizeof(*foo));
```

---

You can do it in-place since you know what values to "rotate in".

```
memmove(foo+shift, foo, (MAX-shift) * sizeof(*foo));
memset(foo, 0, shift * sizeof(*foo));
```

`memmove` must be used instead of `memcpy` since the destination and source buffers may overlap.

Comment: Hmmm, after the`for()`, `shift` can have the values of `0, 2, 3,4,5,6`.  Not all those values work well in the following `mem...()` code.

Comment: @chux How would you fix that?

Comment: @ikegami, Implementing the above yields me a "exit code 139" SIGSEGV. If `bar` is a pointer must I do something special when passing it to `memcpy()`?

Comment: The shift-estimation part is what breaks this.

Comment: @BernardoMeurer I find your post unclear. "all null entries are to the left". What about `0,1,0,2,0`?  This answer is likely on the right track, just needs a minor fix.

Comment: @chux In my use case that will never happen, although I guess finding a more general solution is never bad.

Comment: Fixed. . . . . . .